# Java, типы данных

Tags: java

```
int a = 'a';
int b = ('a' + 'b');
```

`int` объявляется как тип данных `char`, что означают эти строчки?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Смотрите. У вас переменные объявлены как `int`, а вот значение им присваивается с помощью констант типа `char`.

В Java, в отличие от C++, `char`  — [16-битный](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) числовой беззнаковый тип* (в отличие от 8-битного знакового `byte`).

При сложении `char`'ов, однако, происходит [integer promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2): `char`'ы преобразуются к 32-битному типу `int`, и складываются. При этом, очевидно, переполнения не будет.

Результат сложения есть тоже `int`, он-то и присваивается переменной `b`.

---

*хотя его константы (*литералы*) задаются символами вида `'\u1f2d'`, а не числами

Comment: "16-битный _нечисловой_ тип" - вы имели в виду "беззнаковый"? Потому что согласно JLS он вполне себе целочисленный.

Comment: @Roman: Согласно §4.2.1, значения `char` — символы `'\u0000'` .. `'\uffff'`. Мне кажется, это означает, что по сути тип нечисловой, значения не являются числами. Хотя тут же рядом «that is, from 0 to 65535». Так что я не уверен, как правильно это интерпретировать.

Comment: Чуть выше (4.2) там написано: "The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values <...>, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units". Т.е. значения вроде как всё же числа, соответствующие кодам символов.

Comment: @Roman: Ага, вижу. Меня всё же смущает, что `char`-литералы записываются не как числа, а как что-то-в-одинарных-кавычках. Ну хм, подправлю ответ.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле `char` - целочисленный тип, аналог `byte` иногда беззнаковый. Его можно неявно привести в `int` (по коду символа) и сложить. Код не очень красивый и смущает тех кто пришёл из С++.

UPD. Спасибо за уточнения, был не совсем прав, смотри ответ VladD.

Comment: В каком случае будет переполнение?

Comment: @zed например Ё складывать. Или какой там символ последний в алфавите?

Comment: Тут же идёт приведение к `int`.

Comment: @zed если я неправ то поправьте, я к С++ привык. Результат сложения `char + char` это `char` и в `int` уже потом. Т.е. `(int)('a'+'b')` но не `(int)('a') + 'b'`

Comment: Последний "символ" в алфавите, это `\uFFFF` и даже с таким значением переполнения не будет.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, в Java для `char` не определена операция сложения и там происходит вначале преобразование к `int`, а уже потом сложение. Поэтому, переполнения не будет.